# How to move a piece in a checkers game

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

So, I am working on a in-class cooperative assignment in which I must design a partial checkerboard. This must be done using a console window and must be 8x8 board. My friend is designing the board while I design the function to move only the red piece. His part of the code will be sending me a matrix of the coordinates board[rows][columns] and the movement meaning movement = 1 is top left, movement = 2 is top right, etc.. I'm having issues understanding how the pieces are suppose to move.

Here is my code:

```
int movered(int movement, int board[][8])
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int piece;

    for (x=0; x == movement; x++)
    {
        x = movement - x;
        for (y=0; y == movement; y++)
        {
            y = movement - y;
        }
    }

    piece = board[x][y];

    board[x][y] = 0;

    DrawBoard(piece, board);

    return piece;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to this but my shot at it would be something like this.

```
int moved(int xPos, int yPos, int moveSelect, int board[][8])
{
        int teamCheck;

        if(board[xPos][yPos] == 1)
                teamCheck = 1;//else = 2

        if(moveSelect == 1) // && xPos >= 0, etc... Moves can't go off board
        {     
                board[xPos][yPos] = 0; //then set new position on board to equal a 1 or 2 depending on team chip is on
                return 1;
        }
        //elseif - do rest of moveSelections

        else
                return 0; //Returning value indicates a success or failure in move
}
```

Comment: I will try your idea when I have the chance, but desk checking it looks like it will work and is dummy proof. Thanks I will see if the solution works when I'm on my code.

Comment: @RieKumar Okay, don't forget to accept answer if it has solved your problem